# Why am I getting `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'This is full' to data type int.`?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This code has been working for the past one year but suddenly, we started getting:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'This is full' to data type int

Code:

```
CASE 
   WHEN L.Seating_Capacity - COALESCE(TS.TakenSeats,0) = 0 THEN 'This is full'
   WHEN l.location = 'MLK High School' AND d.trainingDates = '5/14/2014' THEN 70 - COALESCE(TS.TakenSeats,0)
   ELSE CAST(L.Seating_Capacity - COALESCE(TS.TakenSeats,0) AS VARCHAR)
END AS 'AvailableSeats'
```

Any ideas what went wrong?

Comment: I'm suspicious of your assertion that it has been working and you suddenly started getting the error -- something changed, either the code or the SQL Server software.

Comment: @Frank, Don't be. No reason for me to lie. If you want sample data from last year, I will be more than happy show it as long as you delete it afterwards.

Comment: I'm not asserting you lied; no reason for me to do that. I'm suggesting you may have missed something... something we wouldn't be able to identify here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `CASE` is an *expression* - it computes a single value, of a single type. So all of the possible `THEN`s (and the `ELSE`) must all produce values that can be converted to a single type. You can't have one `THEN` produce a `varchar` and a different one produce an `int`.

And since `int` has a higher [precedence](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) than `varchar`, that's the single data type that SQL Server tries to convert everything to.

```
CASE WHEN  L.Seating_Capacity - COALESCE(TS.TakenSeats,0) = 0
 THEN 'This is full'
WHEN l.location='MLK High School' AND d.trainingDates = '5/14/2014'
 THEN CONVERT(varchar(10),70 - COALESCE(TS.TakenSeats,0))
ELSE CONVERT(varchar(10),L.Seating_Capacity - COALESCE(TS.TakenSeats,0))
END AS 'AvailableSeats'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt response.

It just so happened that users were screaming after running into the error.